# How to get different value of particular id into single row in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I had an below table

y TABLE

```
id     val
--     ---
1       A 
1       B 
1       C 
2       B
2       C
3       A
```

Need output like below

```
 sno   val1    va2       val3
-----  ----   -----     ------
  1      A     B          C   
  2      B     C          -
  3      A     -          -
```

I wrote query with self join like

```
SELECT t1.id as sno, t1.val as val1, t2.val as va2, t3.val as val3
  FROM y t1 JOIN y t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
  JOIN y t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
  ORDER BY 1,2,3,4;
```

But i returns like Cartesian join. How to get proper result.

Comment: Do you know ahead of time how many `valN` columns you will need? If not, can you limit their number ahead of time, for example only include `val1` to `val3` even if an id actually has more than three "values"? If not (that is: if the number of columns is not known ahead of time, and instead it must depend on the actual data), you can't do this in plain SQL. You will need dynamic SQL, which is an advanced topic, a poor practice, and in almost all cases best left to your *reporting* interface, not done in SQL.

Comment: A quick side comment about your `ORDER BY` clause: you order by columns 1, 2, 3, 4 - which means order by column 1, then if there are ties order by column 2, etc. But in your query, the first column is the id, by which you "group" (you want only one row per id). So, there can't be any ties in the first column. `ORDER BY 1` will do exactly what your `ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4` does, and it's simpler.

Comment: @mathguy In this case i know `valn` it is `val1 to val3` and made mistake in sorting too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then val end) as val_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then val end) as val_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then val end) as val_3
from (select t.*
             row_number() over (partition by id order by val) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to do this in `self join`

Comment: @NaveenM - It is possible, but it depends on what the values may be. Can they ever be NULL - and if so, what is the desired handling? Can they ever be *equal* for the same id? More importantly: What Gordon showed you is a much more efficient way to do the same, even if you fix your repeated self-join. So, why do you want to do it with a self join (even if it can be done)?

Comment: @NaveenM . . . It is not desirable from a performance perspective.

Comment: @mathguy I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Oracle version, you can solve this in different ways. You can fix your self-join (you need left outer joins, not inner joins like you have - with inner joins you will only get the id's that have all three values in the input table, even after you fix the rest of the code). You can use conditional aggregation, as Gordon Linoff has shown; this is how pivoting (the name of the operation you are asking about) used to be done in Oracle up to version 10.2. Since version 11.1 you can do the same with the `pivot` operator.

Since Oracle 12.1, you can do the same with the `match_recognize` clause. Here is how:

```
create table y (id, val) as 
  select 1, 'A'  from dual union all
  select 1, 'B'  from dual union all 
  select 1, 'C'  from dual union all
  select 2, 'B'  from dual union all
  select 2, 'C'  from dual union all
  select 3, 'A'  from dual
;

select id, val1, val2, val3
from   y
match_recognize(
  partition by id
  order     by val
  measures  r1.val as val1, r2.val as val2, r3.val as val3
  pattern   (^ r1 r2? r3?)
  define    r1 as null is null
);

  ID VAL1 VAL2 VAL3
---- ---- ---- ----
   1 A    B    C
   2 B    C
   3 A
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to achieve it using the self join then you need to use `group by` and `self join` as following:

```
SELECT t1.id as sno, min(t1.val) as val1, min(t2.val) as va2, min(t3.val) as val3
  FROM y t1 
  LEFT JOIN y t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.val < t2.val
  LEFT JOIN y t3 ON t2.id = t3.id And t2.val < t3.val
  Group by t1.id
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This shows that you understood some of my comment addressed to the OP (under his question). But did you understand *all* of my comment? Specifically the part where I ask if some values may be equal, even for the same id? If they can, then this answer won't include them in the output.

Comment: Nope, I did not go through the comments. But I have made this answer looking at the sample data. Let OP comeup with the questions now.